# how to wait till we work on opened excel and proceed ruby code once it is closed manually

Tags: ruby, excel, win32ole

I trying to achieve below thing in Ruby

1. Open an Excel

   ```
   require 'win32ole'

   excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
   worksheet  = application.Workbooks.Open("C:/testing.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
   excel.visible = true
   ```
2. Make necessary changes to that opened excel manually, I would like ruby program to wait until I am doing those changes.
3. Once necessary changes are done I close that excel manually using close(X) button.
4. ruby program should proceed and continue to execute next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, where you have

```
worksheet  = application.Workbooks.Open("C:/testing.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

I think you mean

```
worksheet  = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/testing.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Anyway, you can detect how many workbooks are open in the instance of Excel, so you can do

```
while excel.Workbooks.count > 0 do 
    sleep(5)
end
```

and your script will sit there, endlessly polling, until the workbook is closed, and then will continue on.

Note that the instance of Excel will still be running, invisibly, after the user closes it; you may want to call

```
excel.Quit
excel.ole_free
```

to clear it out.

Comment: This worked great! but ended up in new problem, when I try to edit file manually it say's file is open in read-only mode, but obvious as ruby is still using that file, so is there any option that I can use which will allow me to edit file, File mode or something like that.

Comment: On my machine it works fine and allows me to edit the file and save it.  Perhaps you have a previous instance of Excel still open in the background with that file open, or perhaps the file itself has the read-only flag set?

Comment: Thanks! Initially I was running without 'excel.visible = true', so there were so many excel processes running at the backend. I closed them all and reran and it's working as expected.